# Array access producing unwanted result

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse

I am getting an unusual result when attempting to place a value in an array.
I have an array table[] of a simple class result{ int score, long time, string ID}
Intention is to have a sort of leader board.
My code happily finds the correct place to insert a new score if it is in the top 10.

```
    int ix = 0; 
    int jx = 10; //
    while ( ix < jx )
    {
        if (points > sTable[ix].points)
        {
            // score is higher move records down
            for (jx = mNumRecords - 1; jx >ix ; jx--)
            {
                sTable[jx] = sTable[jx -1];
            }
            //now add new score
            sTable[ix].score = score; // all good until here
            sTable[ix].time = time;


        }

        ix++;           
    }
```

Problem is that when I try to insert the score using sTable[ix].score = score;

The value gets written to sTable[ix].score and also sTable[ix +1].score.

It is repeatable, it occurs at any value of ix, I have single stepped through the code and as far as I can tell the command only executes once.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Oh yes. We have ALL seen it before. And we have ALL slapped our foreheads for it. :) Binyamin has the solution right there in his answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

That because you copied the object reference to the next element in the array. You should copy the values, or create a new object:

Option A:

```
// score is higher move records down
for (jx = mNumRecords - 1; jx >ix ; jx--)
{
    sTable[jx].time = sTable[jx -1].time;
    sTable[jx].score = sTable[jx -1].score;
}
//now add new score
sTable[ix].score = score; // all good until here
sTable[ix].time = time;
```

Option B:

```
for (jx = mNumRecords - 1; jx >ix ; jx--)
{
    sTable[jx] = sTable[jx -1];
}
sTable[ix] = new Result(score, time, ""); // Or however you construct the object
```

Comment: Option A solved my problem. Thanks Binyamin. A bit obvious once pointed out (he says slapping head!!)